# Writing right for the community

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to learn how to write math well in the site.  I was asked not to put images but I do not know LaTex.  Do anyone can help me with the correct path for learning writing right for the community?

Thanks

Comment: [look here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Some tutorials are also mentioned in [Do we have an equation editing HOWTO?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) and
[Where is the latex reference please](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please).

Comment: Learning by example is also a good thing. I have no doubt that other MSE users will help you with editing your posts.